# Exchange Server Issue from cancellation of email protection service - Emails stuck in limbo

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365

My company is a small startup without an IT department.  We registered our domain through GoDaddy and then added email service - which runs through Microsoft office 365.

We recently added on an email protection service after becoming concerned about the number of phishing and malware emails making it through the default protection.  We added this on through GoDaddy - it is a service from Inky.

We were not that happy with the actual service and cancelled about 1 day later.  GoDaddy refunded the purchase and that is when the issues started.

All external emails - in and out - stopped getting delivered.  As I understand it (as best I can), the messages were relayed to the inky service by some settings on the exchange server.  However, after cancelling the service, inky rejects the relay but they nor GoDaddy cleaned up the exchange settings.  So the emails are continually pending.

After several support chats with GoDaddy - new emails are working now.  I think that is mainly because I deleted all of the transfer rules plus GoDaddy support made some other "IP settings change".

However, all the emails from between cancelling the service and making those changes are still not coming through.  It has been almost 20 hours now, and we are missing 100+ emails.  These are critical messages from customers and more.

I can do a message trace on the exchange server - and see the "pending" emails.  I have attached the relevant screen shots with anything I think is private redacted.

You can see after a certain time emails work again, but old ones are still stuck in broken transfer rules.

How can I get these emails to come through?

I have spent hours with GoDaddy support.  They have been unable to understand the issue fully and cannot resolve it.  They just keep telling us it will fix itself in a couple of hours - but I don't think it will (it has been overnight).  Inky service has not responded.

I expect after 48 hours these emails will get rejected and we will have lost our chance.

Please let me know anything else I can add.  Thank you!

[Message Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emqwU.png)
[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA7qI.png)
[Message Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSTta.png)
[Defer Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avtCb.png)

Comment: With the server trace report we just contacted all people who sent us emails and informed them of our outage and asked them to resend.  Not the cleanest solution, but had to get practical.

But if anyone does know how to get these out of limbo, the answer is still appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to export all messages stuck the queue from a transport queue, step by step guidance for your reference: [Export messages from Exchange transport queues](https://granikos.eu/export-messages-from-exchange-transport-queues/)

Comment: Thank you for the tip